# Generate Excel file from base64 string in .net core without loosing data format in excel column including Date type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

We have a asp.net core 6 web api application, in which we gets an excel file as base64 string. We have to read the data from excel in the same format as it is uploaded and convert it into xml format and pass to DB. But the issue is when we generate the base64 string to excel in server the date column in excel file will change to server date format. Our DB columns are dynamic so all columns are assigned as varchar. We try to fetch cell text from excel but it requires loop and will affect on large file updation(Taking very long time). We also tried to generate excel with all columns as text, but that changed the date column data to a sequential serial number format. Is there any way that we can fetch the excel data in same format in which it is uploaded with or without any library? We are onto this for many days and really disappointed that we haven't had a solution yet. Will you guys please help to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Which lib do you use to read the Excel file in your app?

Comment: EPPLUS, OLEDB, Spire.XLS  libraries are used but no exact solution for the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.